# 'AMD Display Driver has stopped responding and has recovered' error

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, amd-radeon

I've been getting this strange error on my new Windows 10 laptop lately. When I try to run Assasin's Creed 4:Black Flag or Tombraider 2013, the game goes just fine until where it loads graphics (So the intro video play out fine, but the game itself does not start.), where it either crashes to windows or just remains as a black screen, often requiring me to restart my laptop. The message 'AMD Display Driver has stopped responding and has recovered' pops up occasionally, but not always.

The above mentioned games ran perfectly without any issue until yesterday on the exact same settings. I did not update any drivers or install software that is possibly intrusive during this time. (Only thing I did was update Windows defender and install Windows Movie Maker). I did not experience any issue with overheating when I played these games previously. The computer is still able to run HD videos just fine. This error does not occur when I'm doing other things like browsing the internet.

The only thing that I suspect is that the last time I played Assasin's Creed, the game froze at a particular point and I had to close it via task manager. Then I didn't open it for a day, and the problem started happening from the next day onwards, when I tried to open the game. But I can't see how this can mess with the graphics card/drivers.

I would like to update my display drivers, but I'm living on extremely limited net which makes it difficult to do that. Besides, it was working just fine before. It's especially frustrating since the laptop is barely a week old. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Some specs:
Windows 10
AMD Radeon R5 m330 graphics with 2GB VRAM
4GB RAM
2.2GHz AMD A8 processor.

Under display adapters in Device Manager, it shows two entries:
AMD Radeon R5 M330 
AMD Radeon(TM) R5 Graphics
The driver version is 15.200.1055.0 for both.

Please help!

Comment: You need to try and update the drivers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem myself, so I thought I would answer it.

What I did was go to advanced power options, and turn off PCI Express Link State Power Management. Apparently this is some power saving thingy that was cutting power to the Graphics Card to extend battery life.

Not sure if it would work for everyone, but if you have this error, this step is worth trying out as it is completely risk free and does not take up data either.